# Hide null & empty values from output textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a HTML form I am getting user input with `<input>` and `<select>` fields, once the user enters all relevant fields they click the form submit button and it will be displayed in a `<textarea>` with some basic formatting.

See JS fiddle for example
https://jsfiddle.net/dbyo6ctv/35/

One thing I am struggling with is using if statements to hide the output to the `<textarea>` if values are left empty resulting in 'Null' 'undefined' or a blank space.

Below was my attempt,

`if($('cName').val() === 'undefined'){"$(\n\rName: "+name+").hide();}`

Although this just results in syntax errors.

---

For clarification if the following fields have user input as following,

Client name -> "Test"

Error Message -> (This input is left blank)

Select -> Nothing selected

---

The output shows as

Name: Test

Message:

Select:null

---

How I want it to output in the above situation is as follows,

Name: Test

And all other areas hidden.

---

Thank you for any and all assistance.

---

**Edit**

An example of the end result I am looking to achieve as an output if all fields are filled in,

```
Name                            -    Name
Advised x                       -    Yes
Logged x                        -    Yes

-----------------------------------------------------------------

Describe Issue
¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯
Summary                         -    Summary
Started occurring               -    2018-12-17
Things affected                 -    1

Error message                   -    Errors

-----------------------------------------------------------------

System Information
¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯
System Audit                    -    Yes
Server                          -    Live
Version                         -    1.23.12.312
Win OS Version                  -    Windows 8
System Architecture             -    64bit
MSO version                     -    MSO 365
Antivirus Installed             -    AV here

------------------------------------------------------------------

What actions been taken:
¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯
steps taken

Assistance?                     -    Yes | Initals 


------------------------------------------------------------------

Resolution                      -    Closing
```

The idea is any field that is left empty would be hidden and any line breaks that double up (one after another due to hidden fields) would be hidden too.

Comment: Take a little time and read about form validation - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation

Comment: Actually in this way you are checking if the text typed  inside the textarea is "undefined" as string. I think in your case a simple `if($('cName').val())` should be enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a suggestion to get the output you want and also clean things up a bit:

```
const ret = [
  {id: 'clientName', label: 'Name'},
  {id: 'errorMessage', label: 'Message'},
  {id: 'thingsAffected', label: 'Select', linebreak: true}
].reduce((memo, {id, label, linebreak}) => {
  const val = $(`#${id}`).val();
  if (val) {
    if (linebreak && memo.length) {
      memo.push('-------------------------------------------------------')
    }
    memo.push(`${label}: ${val}`);
  }
  return memo;
}, []).join('\n\r');
```

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dbyo6ctv/38/)

**Explanation:**

1. We start with a list of objects that define the id and a label for each form element we want to include in the result
2. We use a `reduce` on the array because, unlike `map` it enables us to selectively add to the result
3. The initial result of the `reduce` is an empty array - the second parameter to `reduce`
4. On each iteration, we test the get the value of the control - if it's truthy, we add an element to the `reduce` accumulator (what I like to call `memo`
5. At the end, we join the result of the reduce with `'\n\r'`

Comment: This works exactly as I am trying to accomplish, could I get some understanding of what exactly this function does/how it works? For example ``.reduce((memo, {id, label}) => {
    const val = $(`#${id}`).val();
    if (val) {
      memo.push(`${label}: ${val}`);
    }``

Comment: I added an explanation - does it make sense?

Comment: Thank you that is perfect, One last part I forgot, Is there a way to add additional formatting for example like a line break `-------------------------------------------------------` between any of the outputted values where needed? I found I could add a hidden `<input>` with a space as the value and add the following `    {id: 'test', label: '------------------------------'}` to your contribution but it looks a little janky.

Comment: try changing the `join` to `.join('\n\r-------------------------------------------------------\n\r');`

Comment: So this would result in a linebreak between each and every  input from my understanding? The linebreak would only be output between some of the values and not all of them. I will edit my original post to provide an example.

Comment: ok, I updated my answer to selectively add the linebreak. I think I've answered the original question. See if you can adapt my answer to handle the full output you want. If you can't get it, please open a new question